# Ansible version compare failure

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I'm having an issue with a version compare not working for me in Ansible. In this example,     Ansible runs the debug task, but I'm expecting it to be skipped. I'm running version 2.10.7. What am I missing?

```
---
- hosts: hqdbepo1
  gather_facts: true
  become: false
  tasks:
    - name: check NuGet version
      win_shell: (Get-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force | Select-Object Version | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Trim()
      register: nuget_version
      changed_when: false
      check_mode: false

    - name: Ensure the required NuGet package provider version is installed
      debug: var=nuget_version['stdout_lines'][0]
      when: nuget_version['stdout_lines'][0] | string | replace('', '0.0.0.1') is version('2.8.5.0', '<')
```

The nuget_version['stdout_lines'][0] is "3.0.0.1"

Comment: What does `nuget_version['stdout_lines'][0]` display you?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I didn't think to include that to begin with. 3.0.0.1

Comment: Well it all makes sense. `3.0.0.1` is not `<` than `2.8.5.0`, so the task is not skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Turns out I thought the comparison was if 3.0.0.1 < 2.8.5.0, but it's the other way around.